UV radiation from conventional blasts?
Continuing from this question

Blast will produce shockwaves at a close distance, so earplugs are a given. But what about the UV glasses? Temperatures exceeding 2500K are required to produce UV radiation. Sudden combustion of entire mass of wood should produce those temperatures according to my research. Any reason it wouldn't? If it does, then will the radiation be severe enough to require UV glasses?


Entire mass of wood? How much is an entire mass of wood? Are you talking a lumberyard that covers hundreds of acres supplies half a country with wood, or a pile of sticks the size of a bowler hat?

@Escapeddentalpatient. a small block of wood one can hold in hand.

If you are close enough to a large wood fire, UV radiation is the least of your concerns, even more for an explosion.
There is an awful lot of IR radiation and heat which will probably kill you way earlier than the potential cancer caused by being exposed to a tiny bit of UV radiation.
That said, 2500K are not enough to produce sufficient UV radiation: just look at a black body emission spectrum

To have significant emission you need to be way above your 2500K.
